# Unable to load .properties file from classpath in spring boot using java.io.File

Tags: java, spring-boot, io

I am trying to read a file from classpath using java.io.File in a spring boot project but I get java.io.FileNotFoundException erorr. This error only occurs when i execute the project as Jar. If I execute the project in intelliJ it works fine. Can anyone explain If Exclamation sign that is introduced in the file path

> :\C:\workspaces\localdb-service\target\localdb-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\com
> ponents.properties

while executing it as jar causing the error?
File is present in the jar's BOOT-INF\classes so I am unable to understand what is causing the error.

```
public static void loadConfigurations(File propsFile) throws ComponentConfigIntializationException{
    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
        if(props ==null){
            props = new Properties(getDefaultConfigurationValues());
        }
        is = new FileInputStream(propsFile);
        props.load(is);
        populateProperties();
        configurationInitialized = true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LGR.info("Exception# error occurred in loadConfigurations");
        LGR.info(e);
        throw new ComponentConfigIntializationException(e.getCause());
    }

}


public void init() throws ServletException {
        try{
            LGR.info(LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? "--- ComponentConfigurationLoader.init() , Loading component Configurations" : null);
            URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("/"+ ComponentConfigConstants.COMPONENT_CONFIGURATION_FILE);
            File componentConfigFile = new File(resource.getFile());
            if(componentConfigFile.exists()){
                LGR.info(LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? "--- Component.properties exits" : null);
            }else{
                LGR.info(LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? "--- Component.properties does not exits" + componentConfigFile.getPath(): null);
            }
            ComponentConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurations(componentConfigFile);
            ComponentConfigurationProvider.setRealPath(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
            LGR.info(LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? "Configurations Loaded, Starting monitor to observee refresh changings" : null);
            ConfigurationRefresher.startConfigurationMonitoring(componentConfigFile, ComponentConfigurationProvider.getConfigurationRefresherTime());
            initializeSecurityConfigruation(ComponentConfigConstants.SECURITY_FRAME_POLICIES_CONFIGURATION_FILE,true);
            initializeSecurityConfigruation(ComponentConfigConstants.ALLOW_CROSS_DOMAIN_CONFIGURATION_FILE,false);
            initializeBuildConfiguration(ComponentConfigConstants.BUILD_FILE);
        }catch(ComponentConfigIntializationException e){
            LGR.error("#COMPONENT_CONFIG_LOAD_ERROR# Error While Loading Commmon Configurations", e);
        }
        
    }
```

Logs:

> 022-06-21 14:22:43.361  INFO 17392 --- [           main]
> c.i.c.f.s.ComponentConfigurationLoader   : ---
> ComponentConfigurationLoader.init() , Loading component Configurations
> 2022-06-21 14:22:43.361  INFO 17392 --- [           main]
> c.i.c.f.s.ComponentConfigurationLoader   : --- Component.properties
> does not
> exitsfile:\C:\workspaces\localdb-service\target\localdb-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\clas
> ses!\components.properties 2022-06-21 14:22:43.361  INFO 17392 --- [
> main] c.i.c.f.c.ComponentConfigurationProvider : Exception# error
> occurred in loadConfigurations 2022-06-21 14:22:43.361  INFO 17392 ---
> [           main] c.i.c.f.c.ComponentConfigurationProvider :
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> file:\C:\workspaces\localdb-service\target\localdb-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\com
> ponents.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label
> syntax is incorrect) 2022-06-21 14:22:43.376 ERROR 17392 --- [
> main] c.i.c.f.s.ComponentConfigurationLoader   :
> #COMPONENT_CONFIG_LOAD_ERROR# Error While Loading Commmon Configurations
>
> com.i2c.components.framework.exceptions.ComponentConfigIntializationException:
> null
> at com.i2c.components.framework.config.ComponentConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurations(ComponentConfigurationProvider.java:187)
> ~[Components3-Core-1.0.jar!/:na]
> at com.i2c.components.framework.startup.ComponentConfigurationLoader.init(ComponentConfigurationLoader.java:53)
> ~[Components3-Core-1.0.jar!/:na]
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:203) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]

Comment: A path that is supposed to be on the CLASSPATH does not contain `file:` or a drive or an absolute pathname. It is relative to the `target` directory, if not a lower directory. The build system's directory structure will not be there at runtime, and it is therefore pointless to refer to it.

Comment: I am creating path using this.getClass().getResource("filename"), It create the absolute path.

Comment: So what was in the filename? What is the value of `COMPONENT_CONFIGURATION_FILE`? And is it really there?

Comment: Its just name of the file.
public static final String COMPONENT_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "components.properties";

Comment: So show us your evidence that it is where it is supposed to be. But resources are not files. What you got from that call was a URL, and from that you can get an `InputStream` directly. So do that.

Comment: That method should have the prototype `public static void loadConfigurations(URL propsFile)` and pass the result of `xclass.getResource(foo)` to it

Comment: Or use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+ ComponentConfigConstants .COMPONENT_CONFIGURATION_FILE)` to get an `InputStream` in the first place.